# How to convert JSON GET request to HTTP PATCH request

Tags: java, json, post, patch

I want to convert a HTTP GET request to a HTTP PATCH request. I am accessing TFS APIs and I want to lock my build automatically by using a patch request.

Currently I am getting all the information by GET method. Now I want to update `keepForever` from false to true using the HTTP PATCH method. By GET method I am able to do that but now I have to do that by HTTP Patch method.

Can someone help me converting the below code from GET method to POST method?

```
public class Test_URL_Req {

    public static String getURLResponse(String url) {
        try {
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
                // System.out.println(response);
            }
            in.close();
            return response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException{
        String url = "https://tfs.tpsonline.com/IRIS%204.0%20Collection/Main/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=4.1";
        //String url1 ="https://tfs.tpsonline.com/IRIS%204.0%20Collection/Main/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1&definitions=" + Def_id +"&resultFilter=succeeded&$top=1";

        String response  = getURLResponse(url);
       // String response1  = getURLResponse(url1);

        JSONObject obj_JSONObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        JSONArray obj_JSONArray = obj_JSONObject.getJSONArray("value");
        String Def_id=null;
        for(int i=0; i<obj_JSONArray.length();i++)
        {
           JSONObject obj_JSONObject2 = obj_JSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String value = obj_JSONObject2.getString("name");

            String toSearch= "DEVOPS";
           if(value.equals(toSearch)){
                System.out.println("STATUS:-");
                System.out.println(value);
                String result =obj_JSONObject2.getString("name");
                System.out.println("BUILD NAME");
                System.out.println(result);
                Def_id = obj_JSONObject2.get("id").toString();
                System.out.println("DEFINATION ID");
                System.out.println(Def_id);

                break;

            }
        }

        if (Def_id != null)
        {
            String url1 ="https://tfs.tpsonline.com/IRIS%204.0%20Collection/Main/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1&definitions=" + Def_id +"&resultFilter=succeeded&$top=1";
            String response1  = getURLResponse(url1);

            JSONObject obj_JSONObject1 = new JSONObject(response1.toString());
            JSONArray obj_JSONArray1 = obj_JSONObject1.getJSONArray("value");
            String Build_id=null;

            for(int i=0; i<obj_JSONArray1.length();i++)
            {
               JSONObject obj_JSONObject2 = obj_JSONArray1.getJSONObject(i);

                String value = obj_JSONObject2.getString("result");
                //String value = obj_JSONObject2.get("id").toString();
                //System.out.println(value);

                String toSearch1= "succeeded";
               if(value.equals(toSearch1)){

                    System.out.println("#######################################");
                    System.out.println("RESULT");
                    System.out.println(value);

                    String result =obj_JSONObject2.getString("status");
                    System.out.println("STATUS");
                    System.out.println(result);
                    Build_id = obj_JSONObject2.get("id").toString();
                    System.out.println("BUILD ID");
                    System.out.println(Build_id);


                    //boolean  keepForever =obj_JSONObject2.getBoolean("keepForever");

                   //if(keepForever == false)
                   //{
                   //  keepForever=true;

                   //}

                   // System.out.println(keepForever);

               }
            }
            if (Build_id != null)
            {

                String url2= "https://tfs.tpsonline.com/IRIS%204.0%20Collection/Main/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1&buildNumber=" + Build_id;
                String response2  = getURLResponse(url2);

                JSONObject obj_JSONObject2 = new JSONObject(response2.toString());
                JSONArray obj_JSONArray2 = obj_JSONObject2.getJSONArray("value");

                for(int i=0; i<obj_JSONArray2.length();i++)
                {
                   JSONObject obj_JSONObject3 = obj_JSONArray2.getJSONObject(i);

                    String value = obj_JSONObject3.getString("result");
                    //String value = obj_JSONObject2.get("id").toString();
                    //System.out.println(value);

                    String toSearch1= "succeeded";
                   if(value.equals(toSearch1)){
                     boolean keepForever =obj_JSONObject3.put("keepForever", false) != null;

                    if(keepForever == false)
                    {
                        keepForever = true;
                    }
                       System.out.println("#######################################");
                       System.out.println(keepForever);

                   }
                }
        }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question here ?

Comment: @pvpkiran How can i convert the above code From GET to HTTP Patch method

Comment: You need to make a much smaller example rather than dumping all your code in here. Cut out all the extra code you don't need and just give the minimal example of the code you are having problems with.

But better still there are lots of examples of calling patch from Java
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54870/working-example-of-update-using-patch-from-java-on-rest-api

Both of those were found searching for "java call patch" or "java call http patch"

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the below to build PATCH request. However, you should also make sure that your server supports PATCH as its generally unsupported.

```
 public static String getPatchResponse( String url){
      try {
          System.out.println("\nSending 'PATCH' request to URL : " + url);
          URL obj = new URL(url);
          HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
          con.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
          con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
          int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

          System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

          String inputLine;
          StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              response.append(inputLine);
              //System.out.println(response);
          }
          in.close();
        return  response.toString();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: giving this error Sending 'PATCH' request to URL : https://tfs.tpsonline.com/IRIS%204.0%20Collection/Main/_apis/build/builds/53135?api-version=4.1
java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Test_URL_Req.main(Test_URL_Req.java:148)

Comment: giving erorr Invalid HTTP method: PATCH